# Convert FindItemsResults<Appointment> to List<Appointment>

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I have a huge list of resource mailboxes that I am getting all of the calendar items from. Currently to get them from the `FindItemResults<Appointment>` to the `List<Appointment>` I am doing the following:

```
    FindItemsResults<Appointment> tApts = service.FindAppointments(CalendarFolderID, cv);
    Collection<Appointment> tApts2 = tApts.Items;
    List<Appointment> apts = tApts2.Cast<Appointment>().ToList();
```

Is this the best way to do it? It seems quite redundant to go from `FindITemResults` -> `Collection` -> `List`.

Is there a way to bypass that `Collection<Appointment>` conversion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
FindItemsResults<Appointment> tApts = service.FindAppointments(CalendarFolderID, cv);
List<Appointment> apts = tApts.Items.ToList<Appointment>();
```

The Items property is a `Collection<T>` which you can do a `.ToList()` with the extension methods as long as you have `using System.Linq;` defined in your cs file.

Hope this helps.